# CGDisplayCapture and system key events

Tags: cocoa, fullscreen

In my app I uses 2 display, one for the UI and one for rendering with fullscreen `NSOpenGLContext`. I capture the second display with `CGDisplayCapture`, but this capture disable system key events just like ⌘ + tab.

Is there a way to re-enable it or I just take a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware when a display has been captured using CGDisplayCapture all of its key and mouse events are disabled on that display. I don't think you can enable them again without releasing the display.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old thread, but I recently had this problem and found a solution that works (found it in some old Obj-C Apple example code). It appears the solution is to get the events yourself instead of letting the OS deliver them to you. This is the Swift 3 version I'm using (note that there may be some more optimal way to write this code, but it seems to be working for me):

```
CGCaptureAllDisplays()

// Show full screen captured display until Escape key is pressed.
var isInFullScreen = true
while (isInFullScreen) {
    autoreleasepool {
        while let event = NSApp.nextEvent(matching: .any, until: Date.distantPast, inMode: .defaultRunLoopMode, dequeue: true) {
            switch event.type {
            case .keyDown:
                if let key = event.charactersIgnoringModifiers {
                    if key == "\u{001B}" {
                        // Escape key pressed.
                        print("ESCAPE")
                        isInFullScreen = false
                        break
                    }
                }
            default:
                print("<unknown event>")
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

CGReleaseAllDisplays()
```